# Order by ... asc nulls last is slow despite an index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a table `g` containing 160 million entries. It has (amongst others) these three columns:

- `d` (number)
- `a` (date)
- `s` (date)

It also has three indexes:

- `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ix_d_s ON public.g USING btree (d ASC NULLS LAST, s ASC NULLS LAST)`
- `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ux_d_a ON public.g USING btree (d ASC NULLS LAST, a ASC NULLS LAST)`
- `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ix_s ON public.g USING btree (s ASC NULLS LAST)`

Note that the main difference here is: `ix_d_s` is a non-unique index on `d` and `s`, while `ux_d_a` is a unique index on `d` and `a`, and `ix_s` is a non-unique index on `s`.

Now, I run the following queries with the following query times:

```
select * from g where d in (...) order by s asc nulls first limit 15 --1169 ms
select * from g where d in (...) order by s asc nulls last limit 15 --28627 ms
select * from g where d in (...) order by s desc nulls first limit 15 --819 ms
select * from g where d in (...) order by s desc nulls last limit 15 --975 ms

select * from g where d in (...) order by a asc nulls first limit 15 --983 ms
select * from g where d in (...) order by a asc nulls last limit 15 --986 ms
select * from g where d in (...) order by a desc nulls first limit 15 --976 ms
select * from g where d in (...) order by a desc nulls last limit 15 --959 ms
```

All the times are good, except for the second query. I do not understand why this is! Can somebody explain? And why is the ordering by `a` not slow when using `asc nulls last`?

What can I do to improve the performance of the second query?

`PostgreSQL 13.4 (Debian 13.4-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit`

***Edit***

As pointed out in a comment, the `EXPLAIN` query is useful. I ran these before, but did not find answers to my questions. Apparently I was stupid and/or blind, because I did not see a difference before. Well, anyway, here are the outputs for some of the queries. Please note that there is one more index that I did not mention before (my bad - I thought it was not used in this case), I appended it to the index list above.

query 1 (`order by s asc nulls first`)
https://explain.depesz.com/s/O3FM

query 2 (`order by s asc nulls last`) (**slow one**)
https://explain.depesz.com/s/oREo

query 3 (`order by s desc nulls first`)
https://explain.depesz.com/s/9dEE

query 5 (`order by a asc nulls first`)
https://explain.depesz.com/s/enEj

query 6 (`order by a asc nulls last`)
https://explain.depesz.com/s/SJKi

In response to another comment, the IN list contains multiple elements. I ran EXPLAIN on query 2 with a single-element list and it uses the `ix_d_s` query, where a query with a multi-element list does not use it.

Thanks to the comments, I understood a lot more. But what I still do not get is: Using a multi-element IN list, why can query 6 use the index `ux_d_a`, where query 2 can not use index `ix_d_s`? And: where is the difference between query 2 and 3? There is none in the query plan, but the performance difference is extreme.

Answer (score 1):

those are just EXPLAIN, not `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` as requested.  And please don't post text as images.  You can use https://explain.depesz.com/ to share the text of the plans, with nice formatting and options, and with the ability to anonymize things which is much better than just blacking them out.

> why can query 6 use the index ux_d_a, where query 2 can not use index ix_d_s?

You've left enough info unobscured that we can see that query 6 isn't using ux_d_a.  Which is about all we can see.  Also, knowing what index query 2 *does* use is not the same thing as knowing what index it *can* use.

> where is the difference between query 2 and 3?

They start at opposite ends of the index, reading rows in their respective order and applying a filter until they find 15 rows which pass the filter.  Going in one direction, it finds those 15 rows with a lot less filtering than going the other direction.  EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) would have shown this definitively, but even without that we can be pretty sure.

An easy way to improve the performance of query 2, assuming you can control the query text, is to add a dummy operation into the ORDER BY.  This will make the planner think it can't use the index over s to provider the ordering, and will make it use essentially the same plan as query 1 does.

```
order by s + interval '0' asc nulls last limit 15
```

Comment: I updated the question with the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output. Your explanation of the difference between query 2 and 3 was very helpful to me. The explain output confirms your assumption. One question remains - how can I improve the performance of query 2?